# How to fetch last modified dates of ADLS Gen2 files and save it to a csv in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am very new to work with Azure. I need help to fetch the last modified dates from a specific ADLS location and save those information in another container as csv file.

I have my input path as string type.

```
path='teams\test\A.json'

blob.properties.last_modified(path)
```

But it's not working. Kindly help me how can I solve this issue if my file input path is in string format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question mentions ADLS gen2 but in your code sample you are referring to a file in the C drive.
You also need to specify the SAS token of the ADLS Gen 2 blob whose properties you are trying to fetch.

What you will require is the Blobclient. Have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python).

Install the required python lib.

```
pip install azure-storage-blob
```

The python code will look like this.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
sasurl = "xxxxxxx"
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sasurl)
print(blob_client.get_blob_properties().last_modified)
```

Comment: Thanks. I mistakenly provided the local path. I have edited the question.

Comment: No worries. Does my response answer your question? If yes, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Hi @Gorib_coder, Is your question resolved? If yes, kindly mark my reply as the accept answer so the community will know that this question has been closed.